# Green Function for $y''(t)-y(t)=f(t)$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I have to solve this diff equation using Green function where f is a particular function. The first step is :

$(d_{t}^2-1)G(t-t_0)=\delta(t-t_0) $

so i put

$G(t)=(2\pi)^{-1}\int_{R} G(w) e^{iwt} dw $

so i obtain

$G(w)=- \frac{1}{w^2+1}$

using res theorem we have

$G(t)= -\frac{e^{-|t|}}{2}$

Unfortunately it is not the Green function of $(d_{t}^2-1)$ which is

$G(t)= H(t)\sinh(t)$ where H is Heaviside function.

From the homogeneus solution using the continuity and the jump discontinuity of derivative of Green function i get the correct result.

There is another point not clear to me: in this case the Green function (the form from residue theorem) is defined also for negative value of t because for the negative i have the residue in -i. In other situations i could choose the path of integration so that for negative value of t i don't have singularities so the G(t) is equal to zero.

Comment: presumably there are boundary conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that it should be $\sinh(t)H(t)$ and it also appears you are missing a parameter in your solution. I will assume we are looking for solutions which decay at $\pm \infty$ and provide a solution.

In finding a solution to 
$$
(\partial_{t}^2-1)G(t,t_0)=\delta(t-t_0)
$$
we solve the homogeneous ode's to the right and left of the discontinuity of the delta function.

Namely, if $t<t_0$ we have 
$$
(\partial_{t}^2-1)G(t,t_0)=0\implies G(t,t_0)=a(t_0)e^t+b(t_0)e^{-t}
$$
identically, if $t>t_0$ we have
$$
G(t,t_0)=c(t_0)e^t+d(t_0)e^{-t}
$$
Imposing the decay conditions we find $b(t_0)=0=c(t_0)$ and the Green's function is given by 
$$
G(t,t_0)=\begin{cases} a(t_0)e^{t},&t<t_0\\
d(t_0)e^{-t},&t>t_0 \end{cases}
$$
Imposing the continuity condition at $t=t_0$ we have 
$$
a(t_0)e^{t_0}=d(t_0)e^{-t_0}
$$
Imposing the Dirac delta behavior at $t=t_0$ of $LG$ we find 
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{t_0-\epsilon}^{t_0+\epsilon} \partial_{t}^2G(t,t_0)-G(t,t_0)\mathrm dt=1\\
\implies \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{t_0-\epsilon}^{t_0+\epsilon}\partial_t^2G(t,t_0)\mathrm dt=1\\
\implies \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}(G_t(t_0+\epsilon,t_0)-G_t(t_0-\epsilon,t_0))=1\\
\implies -d(t_0)e^{-t_0}-a(t_0)e^{t_0}=1
$$
Solving the system yields
$$
d(t_0)=-\frac12 e^{t_0}\\
a(t_0)=-\frac12 e^{-t_0}
$$
and our Green's function is 
$$
G(t,t_0)=\begin{cases} -\frac12e^{t-t_0},&t<t_0\\
-\frac12e^{t_0-t},&t>t_0 \end{cases}\\
=-\frac12e^{-|t_0-t|}
$$
Note that $G(t,t_0)=G(t_0,t)$ and $G$ in fact a convolution operator, as you would expect since your operator is translation invariant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my notes i have that the right solution is sinh (is left as exer) also i found this table http://www.math.psu.edu/treluga/250/handouts/GreensFunctions3.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my notes i have that the right solution is sinh (is left as exer) also i found this table http://www.math.psu.edu/treluga/250/handouts/GreensFunctions3.pdf . Also in the paper "Renormalization group and singular perturbations..." by Chen Goldenfield and Oono they consider the solution as a sinh

Comment: Well a green’s function need not be unique so there may not be one answer. I can check that that one works and your resources when I have a minute

Comment: @MordinSolus the domain for these Green's functions is also different than what I assumed; the geometry of the problem in general matters quite a bit, as do boundary conditions (which is why I asked for clarification).

Comment: yes, my domain is 0<=x<=1 . i don't know how the result could be different....

Comment: I think the point is that you can always re-define a green function adding the solution of hom problem. it is always a green function and it is verified the relation of the delta. In this situation the solution of the hom problem is Ae^(t-t_0) + Be^(t_0 - t) so in this way imposing the decay condition and G(0)=0 we have that B=0 and A=1/2 so sinh.

Comment: @MordinSolus you should really, really include that in your original question, as well as the boundary conditions.

Comment: You have just illustrated how different domains (and again, boundary conditions are important) give rise to different answers

Comment: sorry but im new in this kind of math but i haven't used any condition about domain, only that G(t_0,t_0)=G(t_0 - t_0)=G(0)=0 and and the decay condition (because it comes from a Schroedinger eq).

Comment: ok, what is the decay condition? Decay *where*? I also had decay at the boundary of my domain, which was $\pm \infty$

Comment: See here: they appear to have arrived at the same answer as me, again, not your answer because the domain is different, http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~jiao/teaching/ams501_fall11/notes/greensfunc.pdf

Comment: @MordinSolus and why should $G(t_0,t_0)=0$?

Comment: @MordinSolus The domain is extremely important to the problem as the Green's function is usually zero on the boundary of the domain. If unstated, it's assumed to be $\Bbb R$, which results in this answer.

Comment: @qbert ok thank you